# Proving $\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta = \sin^2\beta-\cos^2\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove this identity, any idea on how I do it?

$$\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta = \sin^2\beta-\cos^2\alpha$$

Comment: Move the cosines around a bit.

Comment: Basic trig identities should help here. Just look for a trig identity that matches the problem somewhat.

Comment: @DanielFischer How I haven't seen this.... thanks any way :)

Comment: Too bad the equation wasn't $\sin^2\alpha + 1 -\cos^2\beta = \sin^2\beta +1- \cos^2\alpha$. Opps! Did I just give away the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1= \sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha = \sin^2\beta+\cos^2\beta$$
Then by moving cosine's to other sides, we have $$\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta = \sin^2\beta-\cos^2\alpha$$

Answer (score 2):

Simply think to use the identity $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$. Using that for $x=a$ and $x=b$ you get:

$$\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha=1$$
$$\sin^2 \beta+\cos^2 \beta=1$$

Equating LHS, because RHS=1, you get:
$$\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha=\sin^2 \beta+\cos^2 \beta$$

Now, rearrange and prove the final identity:
$$\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta = \sin^2\beta-\cos^2\alpha$$